# Find sequences without final s

Tags: unix, search, terminal, grep, find

I want to search inside a file expressions that don't finish with an "s" like 'regex cats' and 'regex cat', I wish to select only 'cat'. 
I have this one but it isn't working

```
grep "regex \w*[^s]" file.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `-v` flag to negate the pattern.
That is, as the pattern you can use simply `s$` (line ends with "s"),
and then the `-v` flag will reverse the meaning,
printing only lines that don't end with "s".

For example if you have this in `sample.txt`:

> ```
> regex cats
> regex cat
> regex dogs
> ```

Then this command will match only the second line:

```
grep -v 's$' sample.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you could solve it using anchors, in this case to the end of the line, the `$` character:

```
grep 'regex \w*[^s]$' file.txt
```

**EDIT** to add another approach with `perl` regex flavour, using negative look-behind assertion:

```
grep -P 'regex \w+$(?<!s)' file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

using grep

```
echo "apple mangoes plums banana"|grep --colour -o '\(^\| \)[^ ]\+[^s]\( \|$\)'
```

using egrep

```
echo "apple mangoes plums banana"|egrep --colour -o '(^| )[^ ]+[^s]( |$)'
```

the above will match any word ending without `s` begining at the starting of a line, ending of line or any other position on the line and print

I added a --colour switch to colour patterns found